# Why if I enter sentence other scanf is skipped

Tags: c, scanf

If I open enter sentence something like this "asdasd asd asdas sad" for any `char scanf` it will skip other scanfs.

for exapmle if I type for `obligation` scanf `this sentence` it will write for `obligation scanf` this and next scanf will be skipped but automaticly will be field with `sentence word`...

Here is the code:

```
while(cont == 1){
    struct timeval tv;
    char str[12];
    struct tm *tm;

    int days = 1;
    char obligation[1500];
    char dodatno[1500];

    printf("Enter number of days till obligation: ");
    scanf(" %d", &days);
    printf("Enter obligation: ");
    scanf(" %s", obligation);
    printf("Sati: ");
    scanf(" %s", dodatno);

    if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) == -1)
        return -1; /* error occurred */
    tv.tv_sec += days * 24 * 3600; /* add 6 days converted to seconds */
    tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
    /* Format as you want */

    strftime(str, sizeof(str), "%d-%b-%Y", tm);

    FILE * database;
    database = fopen("database", "a+");
    fprintf(database, "%s|%s|%s \n",str,obligation,dodatno);
    fclose(database);

    puts("To finish with adding enter 0 to continue press 1 \n");
    scanf(" %d", &cont);
    }
```

Comment: `%s` stops scanning when it encounters a whitespace character (space, newline etc). Use `%[^\n]` instead

Comment: ... and check the return value from `scanf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` stops scanning when it encounters a [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (space, newline etc). Use the `%[` format specifier instead :

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", obligation);
scanf(" %[^\n]", dodatno);
```

`%[^\n]` tells `scanf` to scan everything until a newline character. It is better to use the length modifier which limits the number of characters to read:

```
scanf(" %1499[^\n]", obligation);
scanf(" %1499[^\n]", dodatno);
```

In this case, it will scan a maximum of 1499 characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator at the end). This prevents [buffer overruns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). You can also check the return value of `scanf` as [@EdHeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal) [suggests in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099508/why-if-i-enter-sentence-other-scanf-is-skipped/31099541#comment50214407_31099508) to check if it was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains several calls to scanf().  the input is a single line, with fields separated by spaces.   So this proposed answer, while containing good information, will not properly read the 4 fields.

Comment: @user3629249 "_the input is a single line, with fields separated by spaces_" -- I don't think that it is just a single line. The OP is mostly going to enter data for each `scanf` and press "enter".

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading character by character. you can use the following function e.g.

```
//reads user input to an array
void readString(char *array, char * prompt, int size) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    char c; int count=0;
    while ( getchar() != '\n' );
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        array[count] = c; count++;
        if (size < count){ break; } //lets u reserve the last index for '\0'
    }
}
//in your main you can simply call this as 
readString(obligation, "Enter obligation", 1500);
```

Comment: This is good, but if I do like this    `readString(obligation, "Enter obligation", 1500);`

    `readString(dodatno, "Enter hours", 1500);` it will skip firt `readString` that is proble

Comment: can you explain a little more what the problem is?

Comment: If the problem is that the input stream is not clean before you start reading, you can call fpurge(stdin) before reading. its like fflush but for input streams and its not standard. Try calling it before every "readString"

Another simple solution would be looping through the buffered input and get them out. while ( getchar() != '\n' );
I have put this solution in readString function just now :)

Comment: The problem is when I try to `2x` run `readString()` it will skip first `readString`

Comment: What really happened in the output? can you post the whole code so I can compile it and see?

Comment: Ok, I will create new question, this is another theme to talk... :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100776/function-to-read-sentence-from-user-input-c

Answer (score -1):

Each successive call to scanf() can have a leading space in the format string.

When the format string contains a space, any 'white space' in the input, where that space is in the input, will be consumed.

This includes tabs, spaces, newlines.

Comment: The blank spaces are irrelevant in this case. Adding or removing them will result in the same behavior as both `%d` and `%s` already scans leading whitespace characters.