# Function to read sentence from user input

Tags: c

I am trying to read sentence from user input problem with my function is it skips second try when I try to call it. Any solution?

```
void readString(char *array, char * prompt, int size) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    char c; int count=0;
    char * send = array;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        send[count] = c; count++;
        if (size < count){ free(array); break; } //lets u reserve the last index for '\0'
        }

    }
```

Here is how try to call it:

```
char obligation[1500];
char dodatno[1500];

readString(obligation, "Enter obligation", 1500);
readString(dodatno, "Enter hours", 1500);
```

Here is example of inputs:
"This is some sentence"

so latter I wana do this:

```
printf(" %s | %s \n",obligation, dodatno);
```

and get:

> This is some sentence|This is another sentence

Comment: Please mention your input(s) and the expected output(s). SOers can help you better then.

Comment: You are right I updated question.

Comment: It would be easier to use `scanf` with `" %[^\n]"` as I mentioned in my answer. Or simply use `fgets`.

Comment: But what if I wana check all caracters from sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go :)

```
void readString(char *array, char * prompt, int size) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    int c; int count=0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        array[count] = c; count++;
        if (count == (size - 1)) { break; }
    }
    array[count] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: This is also wrong. `c` should be an `int` as mentioned by @SouravGhosh and if the `break` statement executes, `array[count] = '\0';` is the same as `array[1500] = '\0';` which writes into an invalid memory location, invoking Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Still problem skips 1st variable :)

Comment: @VladimirDjukic What do you mean by "skips 1st variable"?

Comment: `readString(obligation, "Enter obligation", 150);`  `readString(dodatno, "Enter hours", 150);`   it will skip `obligation` so user will never have chance to input `obligation`...

Comment: @VladimirDjukic Your problem is somewhere else(probably because there is a `scanf` before you call the function). You can fix it by adding `int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` before calling `readString(obligation, "Enter obligation", 150);`. BTW, shouldn't `150` be `1500`?

Comment: If you mean it is taking input from stdin buffer like your first problem, use -while ( getchar() != '\n' ); to make sure you start reading fresh. 
I just put that line in the function but you can also do it before calling readString. If this doesn't solve your problem, please post the whole thing so we know what exactly is happening

Comment: Now I need to enter something for `obligation` then press 2x enter and enter for `dodatno` ... Any way to fix it? :)

Comment: Do you mean, you want newline char '\n' to be read to your array? or do you just wanna press enter twice in which case you can just add getchar(); between your calls

Comment: No, current problem is with `char dodatno` it is empy after user first time insert data...

Comment: If you pressed enter twice YES. because the first one ends the first readString call and the second one will end the second call before it reads anything. so your second array will be empty. 
Once again, posting the whole code would be of great help to help you

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/vforv/reminder/blob/master/Win%2032/reminder/main.c

Comment: Here is proble: 1st time function is called from: `readString(obligation, "Enter obligation \n", 1500);` I type something press enter and obligation is that what I typed, But when function is called 2nd time from `readString(dodatno, "Enter hours \n", 1500);` I will need to press enter and then type and again press enter to sumbit for variable `dodatno`

Comment: @VladimirDjukic delete `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` and `scanf(" %d", &days);` change to `scanf(" %d%*c", &days);`

Comment: Great! Is this part `array[count] = '\0';` reloading array? Also what does this  `%d%*c`? :)

Comment: also remove the unnecessary space in scanf. and I don't know what you mean by reloading array but all that line does is make sure the array has '\0' right after input values so when you read it using %s, it knows when to stop. otherwise it might print some garbage(or memory addresses) next to your input

Comment: About your code in github, I saw a couple of errors like "if(database = fopen(filename, "r"))" which should be "if(database == fopen(filename, "r"))" so I suggest you re-read it :)

Comment: `%*c` for consume newline. Cool Guy already pointed out by his comment for @VladimirDjukic.

Comment: Aha, thanks. Anyone wana be included into my project on git?

Comment: @Lukas Wrong. It should be `=` not `==`.

Comment: yep, my bad :) I use Xcode and it show me error there :/

Answer (score 4):

In your `readString()` function,

1. `array` is not allocated memory dynamically, by `malloc()` or family.

   Calling `free()` with a pointer not allocated memory dynamically creates undefined behavior.
2. `getchar()` returns an `int`. You should change the type of `c` to `int c`.
3. Also, there is no null-termination of your input in `readString()`, so you cannot directly use the arrays as *string*. You need to null-terminate the arrays yourself, used as read buffer to be used as a string later.

Comment: Nice answer. Add that `if (size < count)` needs to be `if (size - 1 < count)`